# SQL query for extracting multiple rows with single date entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "T" that contains Date as one of the column.

In the table, there are multiple rows associated with single date entry.

I want an query that will give me all the rows associated with the latest date available in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where date = (select max(date) from table_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column type is datetime then use this query

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE CAST(<DateColumn> AS DATE) = (SELECT MAX(cast(<DateColumn> AS DATE)) FROM T)
```

and if column type is just date then use this query

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE <DateColumn> = (SELECT MAX(<DateColumn>) FROM T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Group function **Max** when used on date it results in latest date.

```
SELECT <<Columns from table>> T where date = (select max(date) from T);
```